# Python: POST Params

Tags: python

How exactly do I send an HTTP Post Request (using httplib) WITH parameters?

I understand the class. I just don't understand how to send the parameters.

Please include a full sample script.

Comment: Why not include what you have so far and we'll help augment your script.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, try to show some effort of research and/or trying. enjoy :)

Comment: Hey SO, I have a problem - solve it and post the solution!

Comment: The documentation for `httplib`, which is the first hit if you put `httplib` into Google, includes exactly what you are looking for. Please try to help yourself more before depending on others.

Comment: I have looked at the documentation. I didn't get exactly what it meant. Keep in mind I have only been programming as a whole for MAYBE 8 months and I have only programmed in Python for the past 5 weeks. I am understanding as much as I can AND I have looked all over stackoverflow and the documentations as well as many pother example and I simply did not quite understand it. Thanks for all of your support.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example session that shows how to POST requests:

```
>>> import httplib, urllib
>>> params = urllib.urlencode({'@number': 12524, '@type': 'issue', '@action': 'show'})
>>> headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
...            "Accept": "text/plain"}
>>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("bugs.python.org")
>>> conn.request("POST", "", params, headers)
>>> response = conn.getresponse()
>>> print response.status, response.reason
302 Found
>>> data = response.read()
>>> data
'Redirecting to <a href="http://bugs.python.org/issue12524">http://bugs.python.org/issue12524</a>'
>>> conn.close()a
```

from [here](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html)

Answer (score 1):

here's a short script that I use to do exactly what you are asking (this will work if you pass the params in as a dictionary, or associative array):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib
import urllib2
urlencode = urllib.urlencode
urlopen = urllib2.urlopen
Request = urllib2.Request

def request (url, params):
        headers = {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)',
                'Accept': '*/*'
                }
        try:
                data = urlencode(params)
                req = Request(url, data, headers)
                response = urlopen(req)
                return response
        except IOError, e:
                if hasattr(e, 'code'):
                         print '%s - ERROR %s' % (self.url, e.code)
                         return None
                else:
                         return response
```